# How do I show that this is an OR gate?

Tags: voltage, digital-logic, diodes

[image: or gate image]

I need to go through the 4 cases where v1 and v2 are either 0V or 5V, and then use that to show the voltage value of the output, Vo is either low or high.

However, I think I'm hitting a contradiction here. So when V1 is 0V and V2 is 5v, my assumption is that D1 would be off (iD1 = 0A and VD1 < VD0), and that D2 would be on (VD2 = VD0 and iD2 >= 0A). This is a silicon diode so VD0 = 0.7V.

But given that Vo = V1 + VD1 = V2 + VD2, this would lead to the conclusion that Vo = V2 + VD2 = 5.7V. And that Vo = 5.7V = 0 + VD1, so VD1 > VD0!!!

And if I go in the opposite direction, setting D1 to be on and D2 to be off (for the sake of argument), then Vo = V1 + VD1 = 0.7V, which is much closer to 0V than to 5V. The main issue, of course, is that it doesn't makes sense for D2 to be off when it is receiving a 5V input and should be forward biased.

Please let me know what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: What's VD0? There is no D0 in your schematic.

Comment: This uses silicon diodes so VD0 is 0.7 V. I have that in the problem statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Vd goes the wrong direction.

Diodes don't magically "generate" 0.7V, they "drop" that much. the Vdrop is in the anode → cathode direction, so your Vout should really be Vx - Vdrop! (5V - 0.7V)

Comment: And that is only when they are conducting. When they are reverse biased essentially no current flows and the voltage is determined by the external circuit.

Comment: Thanks. I got VD1 to be -4.3V which works for this problem.